# multiple values inside a matrix element matlab?

Tags: matlab

I want to define a matrix in MATLAB such that each element in matrix has 3 elements ,like if i have a matrix m=[a b;c d] a 2x2 matrix such that the element a has values (k,l) like wise b has value (j,m) and so on .

Comment: I don't think you can do this directly... You need either a 3D matrix (like an image) or a second 2D matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can introduce 3-dimensonal matrix. If your matrix size is `NxM` and each element of this matrix contains `k` elements, you define matrix `B` of the size `NxMxK`. By calling `B(2,3,:)` you will access all the elements of the entry `(2,3)`.

Alternatively, you can define a cell matrix, so that every entry is cell array.

If you want each element of your matrix to be consisted of only two real elements, you can define complex-valued matrix.